# keyframe animation on hover

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I have been following an example of CSS keyframe animation with the following code:-

```css
.pulse-animation {
  margin: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff8717;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  float: left;
}

.pulse-animation:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pulse-animation"></span>
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/1.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/3.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/4.jpg" />
```

I try to make the animation working for hover only and it didn't work, I try also to change the hover animation and it still not working so can anyone help.

Comment: if you read you code, you made the animation to be none on hover

Comment: Aly-Elgarhy don't forget to mark the answer that sufficiently answers the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:hover` is the state when you have your mouse above that element.
You don't want to have an animation when you are NOT hovering so you set `animation: none;` on the default state `.pulse-animation`. If you hover the class `.pulse-animation` then you set `animation: pulse 2s infinite;`

see the example below

```css
.pulse-animation {
  margin: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff8717;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: none;
  float: left;
}

.pulse-animation:hover {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pulse-animation"></span>
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/1.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/3.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/4.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's the best Answer

Comment: So How do we reverse the animation with the same softness when we lift the cursor over it ?

Comment: @FatihMertDoğancan You can reverse the whole animation by just adding `animation-direction: reverse;` to the `.pulse-animation:hover` class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to work on hover only, remove the animation from `.pulse-animation` and add the animation to `:hover`, like this:

```
.pulse-animation {
  margin: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff8717;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.pulse-animation:hover {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use animation on :hover-element, you should apply animation for :hover-element.

```css
.pulse-animation {
  margin: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff8717;
  cursor: pointer;
 
  float: left;
}

.pulse-animation:hover {
   animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pulse-animation"></span>
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/1.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/3.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/4.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you've to remove animation on .pulse-animation or animation: none; on .pulse-animation and add same properties on hover .pulse-animation:hover{ }

```css
.pulse-animation {
  margin: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff8717;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: none;
  float: left;
}

.pulse-animation:hover {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/1.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/3.jpg" />
<img class="pulse-animation" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/4.jpg" />
```